# Why Window.ShowDialog runs the application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to open dialog window before the runnig wpf application:

```
public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = new App();
        var win = new MainWindow();
        if (win.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            app.Run();  
        } 
    }
}

class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var win = new Window1();
        win.Show();
    }
}
```

Why does win.ShowDialog() run the app (app.OnStartup is executed)?
But, win.Show() doesn't run the app

```
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = new App();
        var win = new MainWindow();
        win.Show();
        app.Run();
    }
```

Why is this behavior???

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you use for `Show` - you can't use it inside an `if` since it doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: Are you deliberately curious about the workings of wpf or do you just want to solve the issue of showing a dialog before showing the main window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF showing dialog before main window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539958/wpf-showing-dialog-before-main-window)

Comment: @Default 
First of all I want to solve the issue, if possible. But I would also like to understand why this is happening. My issue is not a dublicate of [WPF showing dialog before main window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539958/wpf-showing-dialog-before-main-window)

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog` starts its own message loop. It does almost the same thing as `Application.Run`, and since you already created an instance of the application, the startup message (well, dispatch) has already been sent, and will be interpreted by the message loop (dispatcher) in `ShowDialog`. `Show` basically only sends a message to the queue, so it doesn't do anything unless there's a message loop processing the messages.

If you want to show a dialog before the startup is registered, don't create the application instance before showing the dialog.