# Windows don't open after creation in App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, app.xaml

When I create my MainWindow dynamically in my app.xaml.cs, then mainWindow.Show() function will just be ignored. Every Xaml property, like window.height etc is set to 'NaN'.
Same goes for every other Window, even if I create a new one, with an empty xaml.

What ist strange tho, if I open any Window Before my while loop, like Window1, and show it, all windows after the while loop will open aswell.

Therefore, I could do a workaround, and initialize a window that closes itself instantly. But as said, its just a workaround.

Can anyone recall this strange behavior?

```
private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var win = new Window1();  // if I comment out these two lines,
        win.Show();               // no Windows, except the 'Einloggen' window will be shown

        var i = 0;
        while (i < 3) // 3 mal falsch = Programm wird beendet
        {
            var login = new Einloggen();
            login.ShowDialog(); //ShowDialog is intentional, I want to wait until the user has entered his credentials, then 'login' closes automatically
            if (login.Anmeldeverusch)
            {
                if (login.TBUsername.Text != string.Empty && login.PBPasswort.Password != string.Empty)
                {
                    var log = Login(login.TBUsername.Text, login.PBPasswort.Password); //The Login(string, string) method opens a connection to the Database. If that does not throw an exception, the user is authorized to use the Program, and the method will return True
                    if (log)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
        }

        if (i > 2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Drei fehlgeschlagene Anmeldeversuche!");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show(); // .Show and .ShowDialog() will be ignored. they dont throw an excetption. The entire program just closes after the my App_OnStartup is over
    }
```

Comment: Maybe try not to run `ShowDialog` as first Window. Dialog mean that someone will wait for this window to be closed. Try to use `Einloggen.Show` instead

Comment: @Joschka You want to open all window at same time ? as ShowDialog() function invokes the window modally,Which means code after windowA.ShowDialog(); will not execute until that window is closed

Comment: ShowDialog is intentional, because I want the user to wait until my Login function can return true, and for that the user needs to enter his credentials. if he presses Login in the 'Einloggen' form, the form closes by itself.

Comment: maybe try to Create instance of MainWindow but without opening it, and then call 
`login.Owner = mainWindow`

Comment: sadly, my MainWindow uses the in Login opened Database Connection when it is getting initialized, therefore I cannot create an instance before succefully leaving my while loop

Comment: so try to modify MainWindow that it could initialize without Login window or set owner as any other window. Calling ShowDialog as first window is not good solution, you could also rethink if you couldn't make it other way, like: subscribing to Login.Closed event to open and in event handler open new window or even opening MainWindow from Login window if Login succesed.

Comment: Look at [this ancient Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539958/wpf-showing-dialog-before-main-window) for sample code, some odds it shows you the significance of the ShutdownMode property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem has been solved with the following line, set before opening any window:

```
Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
```